# Dropwizard Migrations with Datical

Tags: database-migration, liquibase, dropwizard

I'm currently using [Dropwizard Migrations](https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/migrations.html), which uses the open source [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) to perform DB migrations. There is an enterprise paid version of liquibase called [Datical](http://www.datical.com/liquibase/), which brings a lot of extra features.

However, I'm wondering if the Dropwizard Migrations extension will work nicely with Datical, since I cannot test it without first paying for it.

Has anyone had this experience? Can I use Liquibase (in my case through Dropwizard Migrations) to run the changesets in development and then use Datical for production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used DropWizard, so I am not positive, but if we assume that DropWizard uses the standard Liquibase APIs, then this should work. Note that I am one of the developers at Datical, so I do have some expertise in this.

If you want to see if it really does work, I would recommend that your organization contact the Datical sales folks, who can set up a Proof-Of-Concept to make sure that it works for your organization.

Comment: Great! We are currently studying the possibility of implementing Datical. I'll suggest the folks here to contact the sales from Datical. Thanks, @stevedonie!